# Best way to synchronize sql

Tags: sql-server

What is the best way to synchronize SQL Server table fields (not data), stored procedures, views and functions?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Red Gate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/).

There are several alternatives, including some at lower cost (or even free). But you often get what you pay for.

The worst option, in my opinion, is to roll your own. I blogged about why (and listed several of the alternatives) here:

http://bertrandaaron.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/

Answer (score 4):

There are tools such as [Red Gate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) that will do this for you - saves a lot of hassle trying to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

As a good alternative to Red Gate Sql Compare I would recommend the following:

Visual Studio 2010 -> Database project -> Schema comparison.